# Default proof size for XCM v2<>v3 compatibility

Tags: xcm, xcmv3

### Code Snippets & Overview

With the introduction of XCM v3, a new `XcmBaseWeight` was introduced both for **Kusama** and **Polkadot** ([here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/ff7448fd03fd3af2464d4d61ca333998b11ad3df/runtime/kusama/src/xcm_config.rs#L100) & [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/dc230b323b5baeb9b4297430ed539b208d30bf6a/runtime/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L105)). The estimate is *64 kB* per instruction:

`pub const BaseXcmWeight: Weight = Weight::from_parts(1_000_000_000, 64 * 1024);`

Inside XCM v3 we also have the same constant defined/used:

```
/// Default value for the proof size weight component. Set at 64 KB.
const DEFAULT_PROOF_SIZE: u64 = 64 * 1024;
```

It's used in various contests, but the one I want to highlight is when V2 XCM instructions are converted into V3 instructions. In particular the `BuyExecution` instruction:

```
// Convert from a v2 instruction to a v3 instruction.
impl<Call> TryFrom<OldInstruction<Call>> for Instruction<Call> {
    type Error = ();
    fn try_from(old_instruction: OldInstruction<Call>) -> result::Result<Self, ()> {
        use OldInstruction::*;
        Ok(match old_instruction {
            ...
            BuyExecution { fees, weight_limit } => Self::BuyExecution {
                fees: fees.try_into()?,
                weight_limit: weight_limit.try_into()?,
            },
            ...
}
```

Weight limit conversion is done using the following piece of code:

```
impl TryFrom<OldWeightLimit> for WeightLimit {
    type Error = ();
    fn try_from(x: OldWeightLimit) -> result::Result<Self, ()> {
        use OldWeightLimit::*;
        match x {
            Limited(w) => Ok(Self::Limited(Weight::from_parts(w, DEFAULT_PROOF_SIZE))),
            Unlimited => Ok(Self::Unlimited),
        }
    }
}
```

### Scenario

I've been testing XCM v3 integration with **Astar**/**Shiden**/**Shibuya** runtimes (using `polkadot-v0.9.39` dependencies), and based on the code examples shared above, I naively also updated the unit weight cost of instructions to:

```
pub UnitWeightCost: Weight = Weight::from_parts(1_000_000_000, 64 * 1024);
```

The scenario which produced an error for me (local `zombienet` setup), one chain is uplifted to use XCM v3, and the other is still on old code revision (XCM v3 not even integrated).

When using the `reserve_transfer_assets` functionality, from V2 chain, to V3 chain, a *Error::Barrier* will happen.

Given the numbers above, it is somehow expected.

- v3 chain receives the v2 instruction sequence
- it converts it into v3 instruction sequence
- v3 `Weigher` will calculate the the required PoV size of the 4 instructions is **256 kB**
- `BuyExecution` will be converted from v2 to v3, and `weight_limit` will end up being **64 kB**

`AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom` will block the execution, since the amount being bought via `BuyExecution` isn't sufficient enough to cover the weight of 4 instructions.

### Question

In case my understanding above is correct (and please correct me if I'm wrong) what would be a good default proof size to choose for instructions?

I'm assuming we keep the default **64 kB** for the `BuyExecution` v2<>v3 conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/7081) covers my question above. It is in fact a bug.